# Script strange behavior CRM online ru12

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Microsoft Dynamics has been nothing but a charm to work with. MS Dynamics CRM is a really good technology but lately everything starts to ... sucks?

Reading from many places i was aware that roll up 12 have some bugs, but i have one customer that works with CRM online and bam! get the update automatically two weeks ago.

And has been a nightmare.

No ribbon buttons support, many bugs all over... and yesterday, **i wrote a script to disable a field, that mysteriously change the process form view (new view) to the classic view. Weird.**

Does Anyone knows if the script design for ru12 has changed? or is it me and my script that is wrong.

```js
function disablefield() {

  //alert ("pass");
  var disable = false;
  var cc = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("field").getValue();

  if (cc == 1) {
     disable = true;
  }
  Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("anotherfield").setDisabled(disable);

  //alert ("pass");
}
```

Comment: In my experience it is more how the code is being called (and when) - can you describe how the script is being called, show the whole function etc

Comment: The script is set On-Save, it's added as a library on the form and it is called for his name "disablefield". I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript code doesn't work in new process view. In future i think this would be supported but now isn't possible.

Comment: there is a way to make it work? all i need is to disable a field, depending on another field's value.

Comment: Yes, turn back to classic forms :D, see this [article](http://nakedcrm.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/limitations-of-the-new-updated-forms-process-flow-top-10/) with more information

Comment: Ok thats exactly what i didn't wanted haha ... anyawy it seems that it's the only way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JS execution system has been remodeled in RU12. Sadly, there are a number of bugs that were introduced. I've seen some funny reports when one saves a form and closes it. Depending on the order of the statements, one gets a number of different behaviors. None of them correct. :)

Comment: This is ugly, CRM 2011 was working pretty well without this "update". When u said "remodeled"... what do u mean? u have any example of some remodeled JScript ?? Thx for the answer!

Comment: Try saving a form and closing it directly afterwards. You'll get the behavior that you get a question if you want to discard the changes or save them. If you select discard, they still get saved anyway (or something like that - I can pull out the exact description, if it's important). Quite quirky behavior, hehe.